# How to return class of element?

Tags: javascript, dom

This may seem like a no-brainer, but I'm wondering how one would go about returning or retrieving the class of an element in accordance to the ECMA-262 3rd Edition specification?

I can't seem to find any info regarding this. Perhaps I'm not using accurate search terms.

Would `className` or `classList` suffice?

I did find [this document](https://ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf). On page 26 it mentions 'Internal Properties and Methods', and, if you scroll down to page 27, there is a chart which I believe might be relevant. But to be honest I'm struggling to understand the documentation :/

Comment: className and classList are DOM properties, and not part of EcmaScript's spec. Do you want to retrieve the string `"Rectangle"` for an instance of `class Rectangle {…}`?

Comment: [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className#Specifications)  and [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Specifications) at MDN.

Comment: @kay nono, i want to retrieve `'rectangle'` from an html context `<div class="rectangle"></div>` and be able to use it in my scripts. however, whatever i do, it must be in accordance to HTML 4.01 Strict and Javascript 1.7/ECMA-262 3rd Edition)

Comment: @Teemu yeah, i've stumbled across that, but i don't understand the info in the table :/ is `className` valid JS 1.7 or in accordance to ECMA-262 3rd Edition?

Comment: It is valid according to any __JS__ version. As kay stated, the both properties are DOM properties, and not specified in any JS standard.

Comment: @Teemu i'm going to have to learn more about this. i'm confused because `className` is obviously a JS method. you say it's valid in any version of JS, but weren't certain methods introduced in certain versions of JS (i.e. the `map` method for arrays)? a more thorough explanation would be a lot more useful

Comment: ?? It is not a part of the JavaScript language, thus not a part of ECMA standards, it is a part of the DOM. Please see the specification tables I've linked above, you can see the links are pointing to HTML Standards, not to ECMA Script standards.

Comment: @Teemu I understand that much now because kay offered an adequate explanation. I'll rephrase my question: Are `classList` or `className` or even `getAttribute('class')` available in DOM level 2? Based on that table I'm assuming this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up unrelated standards. EcmaScript does not care about DOM properties. They are defined in the Document Object Model standard. If your targeted browser / engine is newer than 1997, then you can reliably use [`elem.getAttribute('class').split(/\s+/)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#method-getAttribute) to retrieve a list of classes.

Comment: thank you for this more thorough explanation. i guess i need to rephrase my question. are `classList` or `className` or even `getAttribute('class')` available in DOM level 2? i noticed on MDN's website, in the specifications table it says DOM, so i', assuming this means it was available in the first implementation of the DOM (dom lvl 1?)?

Comment: [Yes](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#ID-011100101), it is in DOM level 1.

Comment: @KarlReid TY<3 god, why are the charts on MDN's website ambiguous when it comes to DOM lvl 1. Why do they call it DOM and not DOM lvl 1?

Comment: @Anthony The page is not ambiguous, "DOM"-link at the MDN page refers to "Living Standard — Last Updated 14 September 2017".

Comment: @Teemu it certainly is ambiguous in the sense that i stated. what? why would i care about when it was last updated?

Comment: MDN is mostly used for bleeding edge technology. Often MSDN pages are better to learn "dated" technologies, because it's most often the internet explorer that's lacking support for current APIs.